# How to migrate empy(scheduler) to RxJS?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have legacy code I need to migrate to RxJS 6.  There is one line that I have no clue how to migrate that one:

```
return empty(this.scheduler);
```

`this.scheduler` is some scheduler passed into the class constructor.

I found instructions on how to migrate `empty()`, just use the contant `EMPTY`, but how can I create an empty observable using a scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update March 2019: There's an opened PR that adds `emptyScheduled()` method: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/4595

The `empty()` Observable creation method is deprecated as well now and the recommended way is using `EMPTY`:

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
```

`EMPTY` just emits the `complete` notification so it doesn't accept any scheduler.

EDIT:

```
import { asyncScheduler, Observable } from 'rxjs'; 

const asyncEmpty = scheduler => new Observable(observer => {
  scheduler.schedule(() => observer.complete());
});

asyncEmpty(asyncScheduler).subscribe({ complete: () => console.log('completed')});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bwn1y7

Comment: Thanks, I did know that. What I want to know is how to get the same WITH a scheduler.

Comment: You can use eg. `asyncScheduler` but I don't think it should matter. At least I can think of any usecase where it makes difference. See my update. Of course you can use any scheduler, not just `asyncScheduler`.